# Modifying Angular Factory Object from inside a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the function that I am working with to call my factory

```
var myService = function($http) {
    return {
        bf: null,

        initialize: function() {
            this.promise = $http.get(this.server + "/requestkey").success(function(data) {
                myService.bf = new Blowfish(data.key);
            });
       }
}
```

And I am creating this object using

```
TicTacTorrent.service('AService', ['$http', myService]);
```

However, when calling AService.initialize() it creates the promise object like it should, but it doesn't update the BF object. I'm confused as to how to update the bf object to be the new value. How would I reference myService.bf since this.bf would create a local instance for .success function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myService = function($http) {
    this.bf = null;
    return {
        bf: this.bf,

        initialize: function() {
            this.promise = $http.get(this.server + "/requestkey").success(function(data) {
                myService.bf = new Blowfish(data.key);
            });
       }
}
```

Comment: This still returns null in the service itself. I'm assuming because the service creates a new instance, that isn't being updated from the myService object anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to initialize?
Have you seen the [$provider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide) example code?
Search for "provider(name, provider)" and check if it suits your need.

Otherwise I'm unsure what the code you'vew written will run like.

I usually write factories like this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var publicObj = {};
    publicObj.bf = ""; // Just to make sure its initialized correctly.
    publicObj.initialize = function() {snip/snap... myService.bf = new Blowfish(data.key);};
    return publicObj;
}]);
```

The difference might be that you previous code returned an inline anonymous object which might have a hard time referring to itself. But by that logic it should work by just making myService return a predeclared var and returning that.

Comment: Initialize is just a fraction of a much larger module. This module is intended to provide login across multiple app's and handles all logins through this object. I've had it previously working through pure javascript, and I just want to turn the object into angular.

Comment: Then it really sounds like you should do it in angulars config (or run function). See [module](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).